# Is it "#1 of a series" or "#1 in a series"?

Tags: word-choice

Am about to produce a series of videos on the same subject, but unrelated. Is it "#1 of a series" or "#1 in a series"? Or am I just over thinking this.

Comment: Do you intend to have "#1" read as "number 1" or "first"?

Comment: Neither. Just ditch the #1 and say *the first of/in a series*. @Catija, I can't really bring myself to read #1 as "first".

Comment: @PhilSweet I can't either... I asked because I agree that "first" is significantly better and I am having issues dealing with the #1.

Answer (score 1):

You might be over-thinking it. That said, I think I prefer the "#1 in a series" more than "#1 of a series". I would be more likely to use "#1 of..." when followed by a specific number, such as: "#1 of 5", whereas I would be less likely to use "#1 *in* 5".

"#1 in...", using *in* followed by an abstract quantity/collective sounds better to me, but that may just be my subjective opinion. For example: "#1 *in* (a) line" compared to "#1 *of* (a) line" or "#1 *in* a collection" or "#1 *of* a collection".

Also, the *of* gives it the feeling that it is a ranking or score rather than a position in a series.